# Request always redirecting to error 403

Tags: php

Recently, I've moved my website from one Webhosting site to another.

Strangely, one of my PHP requests **always** redirects to an error 403 page, but I can't understand why. That same PHP request always worked on the first hosting site.

I've looked around for explanations on error 403, but nothing useful came out.

**Any ideas on why this is happening?**

If it matters, here's my PHP file:

```
<?php 
include "connect.php";

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$duelLink = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linx']);
$thumb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['finger']);
$guy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['guy']);

$timestime = time();
$sql = "UPDATE users SET lastActive='$timestime' WHERE username='$username'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE duels SET checked='Yes' WHERE duelLink='$duelLink'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if ($thumb == "up")
{
$sql = "UPDATE duels SET reality='Real' WHERE duelLink='$duelLink'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
} else if ($thumb == "down")
{
$sql = "UPDATE duels SET reality='Fake' WHERE duelLink='$duelLink'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET warnings=warnings+10 WHERE username='$guy'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$guy'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$banner = $data["warnings"];
}
if ($banner >= 30)
{
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_bio='Banned' WHERE username='$guy'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
print "systemResult=Success";
?>
```

**EDIT:** I also get the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://site.hol.es/site.swf cannot load data from http://error.host.eu/403.php?.
    at _302_fla::MainTimeline/thisImg()
```

**EDIT2:** .htaccess:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. It may very well be that your SQL API is deprecated and has been deleted. See what error reporting gives, and check your logs if there's anything in there.

Comment: Nope, I got nothing... It auto-redirects to the 403 error page, but I do get an error that I updated in the question. Any other ideas?

Comment: A 403 means `Forbidden`. You may have something in `.htaccess` somewhere.

Comment: This is what my .htaccess looks like: # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /  I'll fix up the question again

Comment: Hard to say. Check to see if the new host has any pre-defined rules.

Comment: Have you checked whatever access logs your host permits you to view?  Its hard to say what these are or how you would access them without knowing your host (likely, even if we did).

Comment: Fred, I can't seem to find any rules. And, I don't personally know my host, or know the location of these Access logs... What really confuses me is why This Specific PHP script redirects to 403 while others don't..